# Android Fragment + Tablet = NullPointerException

Tags: android-fragments, nullpointerexception, tablet

My layout is a little bit complex:

I have a vertical viewflipper and on the second page a horizontal viewpager with several fragments.
On the third page I have a listview with a textfild, that can filter the listview depending on the states of togglebuttons in the fragments.

Due to the fact, that the viewflipper has some caching and unload mechanisms for performance reasons, I had to make the references to the togglebuttons in the fragments static:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment { 

public static ToggleButton  btn_1;  
public static ToggleButton  btn_2;
...

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      btn_1     = (ToggleButton)V.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
      btn_2     = (ToggleButton)V.findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
      ...
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but for some reasons only on tablets (manly Galxy Tab3) I get a nullpointerexception when I want to check the state of the Togglebuttons:

```
filterListview(){
   if(FragmentOne.btn_1.isChecked()){ //doSomething };
   ....
}
```

Any Idea what can cause this problem? (btw I don't have any specific layout for tablets, only one layout for the app, and the app always runs in portrait-mode)

Comment: So you're sure you don't have another layout folder, like layout-xlarge? I had a similar issue when I had this because I changed the layout in the regular folder but not the xlarge folder.

Comment: No, only one 'layout'-folder ...